# R Shiny DT - change pageLength to selected row

Tags: shiny, dt

When selecting a row of a DT DataTable, is it possible to hide all the other rows - then when selecting the row again these hidden rows are made visible again?

Investigating the pageLength option, which can be manipulated by users during runtime, it doesn't seem accessible through proxy: the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/DT/man/proxy.html) doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I offer the following solution. Here are the table and action button. When you select row(s) and click the button you can see a pop-up window with detail information about selected row(s).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# 1. UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(actionButton("md_data_profile", "Details for selected row")),
  fluidRow(dataTableOutput("dt_data"))
)

# 2. Server
server <- function(input, output) {

  # 1. Data set
  df_data <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })

  # 2. Data table
  output$dt_data <- renderDataTable(
    datatable(df_data()))

  # 3. Details as Popup window
  observeEvent(input$md_data_profile, {

    # 3.1. Get selected rows
    selected_row <- input$dt_data_rows_selected

    # 3.2. Process selected row
    if(!is.null(selected_row)){
      df <- df_data()[selected_row, ]
      popup_str <- paste0("Mpg: ", df$mpg)
    } else {
      popup_str <- "Please, select row to see details"
    }

    # 3.3. Create model dialog window
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Data profile", HTML(popup_str), easyClose = TRUE))
  })
}

# 3. Application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This provides a popup for the row selected. I'm looking to hide the other rows - the purpose is not to view more information about the selected row, it is to hide the other rows to make room for the other elements on the screen.